# redirect to a different homepage following user role using FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle, redirect

In my Symfony application I am using the FOSUserBundle.

It's an application involved two main Roles of User: Factory as `ROLE_FACTORY` and Custommer as `ROLE_CUSTOMER`.

I have a main page for non-connected user, it's the home page of the application.

But when User is going to be connected or is connected, following the role he has, the home page has to change.

So the fos user login action have to redirect to the right page.

`ROLE_FACTORY` have to be redirect to the `factory_homepage` route.
`ROLE_CUSTOMER` have to be redirect to the `customer_homepage` route.

How can I create this behavior in the **best practice** using `Symfony` and `FOSUSerBundle`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off there is no best practice for this. So I leave that decision of selecting one of these options to you whichever suits you according to your needs.

### OPTION 1:

You have to implement an `EventListener` in this case.

#### STEP 1)

Register a service

```
<service id="acme_demo.listener.login" class="Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\LoginListener" scope="request">
    <tag name="kernel.event_listener" event="security.interactive_login" method="onSecurityInteractiveLogin"/>
    <argument type="service" id="router"/>
    <argument type="service" id="security.context"/>
    <argument type="service" id="event_dispatcher"/>
</service>
```

#### STEP 2)

Your `EventListener` itself

```
class LoginListener
{
    protected $router;
    protected $security;
    protected $dispatcher;

    public function __construct(Router $router, SecurityContext $security, EventDispatcher $dispatcher)
    {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
        $this->dispatcher = $dispatcher;
    }

    public function onSecurityInteractiveLogin(InteractiveLoginEvent $event)
    {
        $this->dispatcher->addListener(KernelEvents::RESPONSE, array($this, 'onKernelResponse'));
    }

    public function onKernelResponse(FilterResponseEvent $event)
    {
        if ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_FACTORY')) 
        {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('factory_homepage'));
        } 
        elseif ($this->security->isGranted('ROLE_CUSTOMER')) 
        {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('customer_homepage'));
        } 
        else 
        {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('default_homepage'));
        }

        $event->setResponse($response);
    }
}
```

### OPTION 2:

You can modify the vendor code at [FOSUserBundle\Controller\SecurityController](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Controller/SecurityController.php) Add the following piece of code to make your `loginAction` look like this

```
public function loginAction(Request $request)
{
    $securityContext = $this->container->get('security.context');
    $router = $this->container->get('router');

    if ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_FACTORY')) 
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('factory_homepage'));
    }
    elseif ($securityContext->isGranted('ROLE_CUSTOMER')) 
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('customer_homepage'));
    }
    else
    {
        return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('default_homepage'));
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I have not my code with me yet, let me try your suggestion tomorrow and I will make you a return for this post.
However, I don't think that edit the FOS vendors are a good think, the event listener seems to be a good idea.But thank you a lot to reply !

Comment: Like I said it depends on what you want. and modifications happen all the time. Even the creator of FOSUserBundle suggests to do modifications if needed. Your welcome. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: I will try the two options anyway, I am curious to try it all. And of course I'll let you know.

Comment: If this answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted so that it helps future users of the site.

Comment: @DipenShah I just implement your code (Option 1), and It wotks fine after imported the Component of Symfony we need. Could I make some changes to your answer (edit a little your post) in order to be clear for other stackoverflow users ?
Thank you by the way, your solution rocks and illuminate my day code, it's a perfect solution.

Comment: Thanks you I'm glad it can help you. Sure go ahead and edit it.

Comment: never touch the vendor files. if you want to modify something so override it