# Redirect to different locations based on the role with FOSUserBundle

Tags: php, symfony

I have looked everywhere, and tried everything, but my redirect still doesn't want to work.

I have done option two of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682205/redirect-to-a-different-homepage-following-user-role-using-fosuserbundle) question's answer but the wanted results doesn't appear.

This is my overwritten login function (inside `/src/Acme/UserBundle/Controller/SecurityController.php`);

```
class SecurityController extends BaseController
{
    public function loginAction(Request $request)
    {        
        /** @var $session \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session */
        $session = $request->getSession();

        $authChecker = $this->container->get('security.authorization_checker');
        $router = $this->container->get('router');

        if ($authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('admin_home'), 307);
        } 

        if ($authChecker->isGranted('ROLE_USER')) {
            return new RedirectResponse($router->generate('user_home'), 307);
        }
        ...
        ...
    }
}
```

I have my `AcmeUserBundle.php` inside `/src/Acme/UserBundle/` containing the following code;

```
namespace Acme\UserBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class AcmeUserBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOSUserBundle';
    }
}
```

Then I have my main application bundle `AppBundle` next to `Acme` inside `/src/` with my `DefaultController.php` inside `/Controller/` and my admin controller as `DefaultController.php` inside `/Controller/Admin/`

When I log in with a user with role `ROLE_USER`, it goes to the correct location. But when I log in with role `ROLE_ADMIN` he goes to the same location as `ROLE_USER`. It is suppose to go to the admin page.

This is my `security.yml` file;

```
security:
    encoders:
        FOS\UserBundle\Model\UserInterface: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

    providers:
        fos_userbundle:
            id: fos_user.user_provider.username

    firewalls:
        main:
            pattern: ^/
            form_login:
                provider: fos_userbundle
                csrf_token_generator: security.csrf.token_manager
            logout:       true
            anonymous:    true

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/login$, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/register, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/resetting, role: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/, role: ROLE_USER }
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

In my project's profiler the user role for a normally registered user state `ROLE_USER`. I modified a user's role in my database to be `ROLE_ADMIN` and when I log in with him both roles shows to be assigned to him. Under the `role` column in my database this is how it looks for a user with `ROLE_USER` assigned to him :

> a:0:{}

and this is how I modified the other user to have `ROLE_ADMIN`:

> a:1:{i:0;s:10:"ROLE_ADMIN";}

Is this right? Can somebody please help me to fix this problem?

NOTE: When I sign in with a `ROLE_USER` user and I modify the url to go to /admin/ I get a "Expression "has_role('ROLE_ADMIN')" denied access." error. I get that, that's fine because I don't want a normal user to access that area. But when I login with a `ROLE_ADMIN` user and modify the url to /admin/ it does go to that page, so I can see by that that my ROLES are working fine and the routing as well, but the redirect on login not.

Clearing my cache also didn't do the trick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a little known `success_handler` option in `form_login` (at least), here you can find a [gist with example usage](https://gist.github.com/marydn/8061424) suiting your needs just perfectly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've seen this way to do it, but I will keep it for later if I can't get mine to work. I actually want to know what's wrong with my own attempt. It feels as if the logic falls straight through the added part in the `loginAction`, and that it never even triggers.

Comment: IIRC Symfony intercepts request that is meant to authenticate user, it never gets to your action hence your logic wasn't triggered.

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it...

```
// AppBundle\Security\LoginSuccessHandler.php

namespace AppBundle\Security;

use Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Authentication\AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authentication\Token\TokenInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\Authorization\AuthorizationChecker;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RedirectResponse;
use Symfony\Component\Routing\Router;

class LoginSuccessHandler implements AuthenticationSuccessHandlerInterface {

    protected $router;
    protected $authorizationChecker;

    public function __construct(Router $router, AuthorizationChecker $authorizationChecker) {
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->authorizationChecker = $authorizationChecker;
    }

    public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token) {

        $response = null;
        if ($this->authorizationChecker->isGranted('ROLE_ADMIN')) {
            $response = new RedirectResponse($this->router->generate('admin'));
        } 

        return $response;
    }

}
```

Then add this to your services.yml file:

```
authentication.handler.login_success_handler:
    class:  AppBundle\Security\LoginSuccessHandler
    arguments:  ['@router', '@security.authorization_checker']
```

I can't remember if there were other steps.. Pretty sure the services file entry takes care of making sure that class gets called.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've test it really quick and so far it didn't work. I can try again later. I actually want to know what's wrong with my own attempt. It feels as if the logic falls straight through the added part in the `loginAction`, and that it never even triggers.

Comment: After adding this line `success_handler:     authentication.handler.login_success_handler` to my `security.yml` I finally got it to work. Your answer is roughly the same as the other answer's link but there it is a bit more complete so I am going to accept the other one as the correct answer that helped me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: yes i actually looked at the above answer after I posted and realized the they were pretty much the same...And yes i guess that't the part I couldn't remember. The important thing is you figured it out.